# Form Submit Not Working on the integration of HDIV and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, hdiv

I managed to integrate HDIV and Spring MVC. Now HDIV generated security URLs for the static links. But when I tries to submit a link with a parameter, I always get error message. I know the reason is when the URL of a form is generated, the parameter is not a part of the URL. But I cannot find a workaround. Please help. Thanks a lot.

The form part is like this:

```
<c:url var="url" value="/contract/report/report" />
<form:form action="${url}"  method="get">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <td><label>Name:</label></td>
            <td><select id="nameId" name="nameId">
                <c:forEach var="c" items="${Users}">
                    <option value='${c.id}'> ${c.name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> </td>
            <td><Button type="submit" >Submit</Button>  </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

**Update:**

I found the workaround is I have to rewrite the select options with spring options like this:

```
<form:select path="contractId">
 <c:forEach var="c" items="${Users}">
     <form:option value="${c.id}" label="${c.name}"></form:option>
 <c:forEach var="c" items="${Users}">
</form:select>
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: For forms you don't need use `curl`. If configured properly there should be a hidden field with the HDIV state. Check your generated source.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a parameter to the URL then this might work.

```
<c:url var="url" value="/contract/report/report"><c:param name="parameter" value="value" /></c:url>
```

Comment: It will not work because the value of the parameter(userId) is from a drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `c:url` for forms, you don't need it:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/contract/report/report" method="get">
     ...
</form:form>
```

Comment: There is no hidden HDIV state if I use this method. But I will get another issue.When I click the submit button, the page URL becomes : http://localhost:8080/myapp/contract/report/report?contractId=1. The new generated URL will be a security URL which HDIV wont recognize it without HDIV state. I get the error  HDIV_PARAMETER_NOT_EXISTS now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround is I have to rewrite the select options with spring options like this:

```
<form:select path="contractId">
 <c:forEach var="c" items="${Users}">
     <form:option value="${c.id}" label="${c.name}"></form:option>
 <c:forEach var="c" items="${Users}">
</form:select>
```

Thanks everyone.